# read linked list from file c++

Tags: c++

Im trying to read a linked list from a file.  but for some reason, its not even reading the content of the file.

This is the structure of the file:

```
Product 1
Category
22.33
Product 2
Category
44.23
Product 3
Category 
66.55
```

and this is the function to read the content of the file. it calls on the addproduct function to add the items it read in a sorted order.

```
void load (NodePtr head)
        {
            // create a variable to attach to the file
            ifstream input;
            input.open("data.txt");

            // check to see if the file opened correctly, and if not, exit program
            if (input.fail())
            {
                cout << "\n Data file not found \n";
                return;
            }
            ListItemType data; 


            while((! input.eof()) && (head != NULL) )
            {
                input >> data.productname;
                input >> data.category;
                    input >> data.productprice;

                addproduct(head, data);
            }
```

Comment: why is head != NULL there? head is probably null every time you call the function since there isn't data in head until you call the function.

Comment: do you expect any errors if please release the error message i think your code is fine in while condition you can use input.good()

Comment: also, if head!=NULL isn't the problem, it doesn't look like your receiving the new pointer of head when the function returns. that may or may not be a problem depending if it's a fifo list or not

Comment: **its not even reading the content of the file**. how do you prove that? show the `addproduct()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to receive the new pointer of head. instead of returning void, return NodePtr.

```
NodePtr load( NodePtr head ){

    ...
    return head;
}
```

Comment: what the OP is doing is acceptable. he is checking if `head` is `NULL`(which it could be), before calling `addproduct()` without checking he might be sending a NULLed pointer which might result in segfaults.

Comment: okay, I was under the assumption that addproduct allocated memory on the list.

Comment: getting rid of  ( head != NULL ) causes an error and returning a nodeptr still doesnt work

Comment: my answer is invalid if the list is a first-in first-out list btw

Comment: as well as how you know the list isn't getting any data

Comment: @user1896464 getting rid of `( head != NULL )` should not cause compile time error.

Comment: i know its not working cus i have a function that goes through to see the number of items in the linked list. and i dont wanna show the addproduct() because this is a assignment, and i'm one of the few students with a working program. if i post my code other students might find it on google.

Comment: It works if i put the code in main but doesnt work if i put it in a function and call on that function from main.